# Making friend template functions in non-template classes

Tags: c++, templates

I tried compiling my code without templates and it works just fine when I add the template code I get a 2019LNK error.

I have the following at the beginning of my class:

```
template<typename T>
friend void inchealth(T &,int);
```

declaration of function:

```
template<typename T>
void inchealth(T &x, int y)
{x.health += y;}
```

(health is a member variable of my class)

EDIT here is the exact code:

```
class archer        
{

template <class T>
friend void inchealth(T &,int);

public:
archer(){health = 150; mana = 50; armor = 50; damage = 10;}

int checkhealth() {return health;}
int checkmana() {return mana;}
int checkarmor() {return armor;}
int checkdamage(){return damage;}


private:
int health;
int mana; 
int armor;
int damage;};

template <class T>
void inchealth(T &x, int y)
{x.health += y;}

void main()
{
archer a;
inchealth(a,5);

}
```

Comment: More context needed. Also, is the error the same if you leave the `inchealth` body empty (it should)?

Comment: In what file is `inchealth` defined?

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://ideone.com/V1d50N)

Comment: @k-ballo yes the error is the same

Comment: It don't know if it has anything to do with your problem, but you should declare main as `int main()`

Comment: @n.m. the function is in a source file linked to the header file containing the class

Comment: It sounds like that's your problem. Move it (the definition) to your header file.

Comment: thank you @GuyRT I fixed it, had a problem with my headers

Answer (score 2):

My psychic debugging senses suggest you've put the definition of `inchealth` in a separate cpp file to `main`.

Templated function bodies need to be visible at the point where you call them, or you need to explicitly tell the compiler to instantiate the versions you want.

So, if I am correct, the solution is either move the definition of `inchealth` to a header #included from the file that defines `main`, or to add the line

```
template void inchealth<archer>(archer&,int);
```

below the definition of `inchealth` in the file where it is defined (assuming the declaration of `archer` is visible there`). The former is preferred.